# How to offload blocking operation to a worker Verticle using websockets and async request

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x

I implementing websockets using Vert.x 3.

The scenario is simple: opening socket from client doing some 'blocking' work at the vertex verticle worker and when finish response with the answer to the client(via the open socket)

Please tell me if I am doing it right:

Created VertxWebsocketServerVerticle. as soon as the websocket is opening and request coming from the client I am using eventBus and passing the message to

EventBusReceiverVerticle. there I am doing blocking operation.

how I am actually sending back the response back to VertxWebsocketServerVerticle and sending it back to the client?

code:

Main class:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
       vertx.deployVerticle(new EventBusReceiverVerticle("R1"),new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));
        vertx.deployVerticle(new VertxWebsocketServerVerticle());
}
```

VertxWebsocketServerVerticle:

```
public class VertxWebsocketServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    public void start() {
        vertx.createHttpServer().websocketHandler(webSocketHandler -> {

            System.out.println("Connected!");
            Buffer buff = Buffer.buffer().appendInt(12).appendString("foo");
            webSocketHandler.writeFinalBinaryFrame(buff);
            webSocketHandler.handler(buffer -> {
                String inputString = buffer.getString(0, buffer.length());
                System.out.println("inputString=" + inputString);
                vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                    vertx.eventBus().send("anAddress", inputString, event -> System.out.printf("got back from reply"));
                    future.complete();
                }, res -> {
                    if (res.succeeded()) {
                        webSocketHandler.writeFinalTextFrame("output=" + inputString + "_result");
                    }
                });

            });
        }).listen(8080);
    }


    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

EventBusReceiverVerticle :

```
public class EventBusReceiverVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

        private String name = null;

        public EventBusReceiverVerticle(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
            vertx.eventBus().consumer("anAddress", message -> {
                System.out.println(this.name +
                        " received message: " +
                        message.body());
                try {
                    //doing some looong work..
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.printf("finished waiting\n");
                    startFuture.complete();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I always get:

```
WARNING: Message reply handler timed out as no reply was received - it will be removed
```

github project at: https://github.com/IdanFridman/VertxAndWebSockets
thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are blocking your websocket handler until it receives a reply for the sent message to the *EventBus*, which will not, in fact, be received until the set up delay of **10s** laps, you certainly will get warning since the reply handler of the event bus will timeout -> Message sent but no response received before the timeout delay.

Actually I don't know if you are just experimenting the *Vert.x* toolkit or you are trying to fulfill some requirement, but certainly you have to adapt your code to match in the *Vert.x* spirit:

- First you should better not block until a message is received in your websocket handler, keep in mind that everything is asynchrounous when it comes to *Vert.x*.
- In order to sleep for some time, use the *Vert.x* way and not the `Thread.sleep(delay)`, i.e. `vertx.setTimer(...)`.

Comment: I am trying to offload blocking operation to my verticle worker and keep that socket open for future messages without blocking the main event looper